# Autocad 2020 Visual Studio version

Tags: visual-studio, autodesk-forge, autocad

I would like to begin coding for Autocad using Visual Studio.

In this post it is mentioned that Autocad 2020 can be compiled in VIsual Studio 2017-15.7:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/objectarx/information-about-which-visual-studio-versions-needed-for/td-p/9443842

Is this the minor version and can it also be compiled in newer versions of Visual Studio? (for instance, visual studio 2022)?

Also, what is the meaning of "API Binary Breaking" set to NO under Autocad 2020?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify your formulation of the question, you are not compiling AutoCAD 2020, but an ObjectARX add-in for AutoCAD 2020.

You can probably use more recent versions of Visual Studio, but you may need to install the exact correct corresponding version of the underlying C++ compiler.

On details of this version of VS, please refer to the detailed [release notes from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.7).

Regarding the system requirements for compiling an ObjectARX app, please refer to the corresponding [list of ObjectARX system requirements](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/autocad/objectarx-system-requirements).

"API Binary Breaking" set to NO for AutoCAD 2020 means that it will load and execute ObjectARX applications built for the preceding version of AutoCAD, AutoCAD 2019.